# Close File stored in Map in Rust

Tags: file, rust, io

I store opened files in a map: `HashMap<u32, File>`. Sometimes functions `read_to_file` and `write_to_file` are called. They get the file from the map and make the corresponding procedure. In order to avoid conflicts in writing and reading from the same file, I need to close the file. How can I do it?

Comment: Closing the file is done by dropping the `std::fs::File`, which you probably do not want or can do in the data structure you have. To avoid conflicts as you describe, you could wrap the `File` in a [`std::cell::RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) and use `try_borrow_mut()` whenever you want to write to `File`, and `try_borrow()` whenever reading from it. Having a mutable reference to `std::fs::File` is actually not required to write to it but in this way you make reading/writing mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user2722968 I write and read to the different objects (so I have two files opened: one for reading and one for writing) that both refer to the same file on the hard drive

Comment: Can `sync_data` be of use here? https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_data

Comment: Does this make sense: ```let f: File = self.streams.remove(&stream_id).unwrap();
            drop(f);``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Rust [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) `std::fs::File` is:

> A reference to an open file on the filesystem.

If you are storing `File`s in a map then they are, by definition, open. They close automatically when the variable is dropped (goes out of scope).

Instead, you may consider storing a `Path` in the map, and open the file on demand. If you need to store open files for some reason, then you can wrap them in an `Arc<Mutex>` (or an `Rc if your application is single-threaded), to prevent simultaneous access.

Comment: When I remove the File from the map, does it automatically mean that the variable is dropped?

Comment: Probably yes. If you don't do anything else with it.